# How to solve lint warning "field is never used" but it is serialized

Tags: java, android, lint

I have a small class in my Android project containing some variables,  I assign them in the constructor.

I then serialize the object to json using the Gson library and the function `String Gson::toJson(Object src)`

How can I solve this lint warning : "private field is assigned but never accessed" on these variables? Is there a special comment for that case?

edit : sorry there is another warning too "Field can be converted to a local variable" which is wrong!

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation on field which will prevent generating such messages.

Comment: Was going to give a +1... but you spelled SuppressWarnings wrong. :-\

Comment: I gave you a +1 because anyone not smart enough to see the typo couldn't use your answer anyway. : )